# How to trouble-shoot alert error message with no information

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

I am receiving the following error on a site component list view "Error  An error has occurred." That's it. Nothing said of what caused it, where the error occurred or anything else.

By searching the component folder I found the view.html.php file associated with this view so I modified the only error exception message I could find (added -Tasks view error- after the \n in the Exception message), but the error message on the site did not change. This leads me to believe it is coming from somewhere else. Searching the entire component folder for 'Error', 'enqueueMessage', or 'error' did not reveal any obvious culprits.
Any ideas on how to proceed in tracking this down?

Thanks in advance!

**view.html.php** (view being displayed when error occurs)

```
public function display($tpl = null)
{
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    $this->state = $this->get('State');
    $this->items = $this->get('Items');
    $this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
    $this->params = $app->getParams('com_todo');
    $this->filterForm = $this->get('FilterForm');
    $this->activeFilters = $this->get('ActiveFilters');

    // Check for errors.
    if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
    {
        throw new Exception(implode("\n", $errors));
    }

    $this->_prepareDocument();
    parent::display($tpl);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found where the error is being generated. I had looked through the Joomla debug info but mistakenly misread an error message as a 'Duplicate queries" message. For those who do not know, the Joomla debug information is displayed at the bottom of the page and can be turned on by logging into the Adminstrator's panel and going to Global Configuration->System tab->Debug Settings=yes.