# Contacts - Error Occurred When Editing

Tags: joomla-3.x, error-handling, com-contacts

Joomla 3.9.11

Whenever I am editing a contact I can see the following error on the page;

> Error
>
> An error has occurred.

No other information.

I am able to edit and save the contacts, so there is no actual error that I can see.

I have created custom fields for my contacts, these are also working as expected so I'm at a loss here :/

What should I check in order to troubleshoot this? I'd rather not just ignore it.

Comment: I don't know if you tried anything, so I'll refer to things I found when I Google searched for `joomla Error An error has occurred.`  ... https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/22675/12352 , https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/22844/12352, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36520472/2943403 , https://www.itoctopus.com/500-an-error-has-occurred-message-when-trying-to-login-to-joomlas-backend